# Mapbox Project Layer Limit (Only 15 Layers)

Tags: mapbox

I have created a project in mapbox. I have multiple layers of point, lines and polygon features, which are uploaded through its online uploading facility of .mbtiles. Mapbox project only support 15 layers, whereas I have multiple layers more than 15 to upload, and now I want to combine multiple layers.

While searching I've found this help from mapbox "Each MBTiles file you upload to Mapbox can be up to 5GB. Larger projects can be uploaded by splitting the export up into multiple smaller MBTiles files. Once uploaded, you can combine them together with the project editor. This just refers to the transfer limit and should not be confused with your storage limit."

In Mapbox Project Editor I have not find any layer combine facility ... Please help me

Answer (score 1):

The combination referenced in the help refers to adding the layers individually with the data manager. 15 is the limit so you may have to combine layers in TileMill.